# Bind the content of a DOM node in WebView to StringProperty

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview

I have been trying to bind the content of a DOM node inside a html document in a WebView to a StringProperty. What I have is something like this:

```
final String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><script>function get(){return document.getElementsById('code')[0];}</script><style>body{font-family:\"Monospaced\";}</style></head><body><pre id=\"code\"></pre></body></html>";

engine.loadContent(html);
final JSObject pre = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("get()"); // Defined in html

property.addListener((ob, o, n) -> {
    pre.setMember("innerHTML", n);
});
```

When I execute the program and modifies the StringProperty I get an exception like this:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: get

I am not sure I am on the right track. It seems like it should be possible to listen for changes in the property and push those changes to the document using javascript. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Content in a `WebView` is loaded asynchronously. You have to wait for the `WebView` to finish loading the content.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getElementsById` function in Javascript. IDs are unique. Use either `getElementById` (not elements, and no array notation) or use another selector if you need more than one.

JSFiddle example base on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/jkennaly/db88u9f3/3/

Comment: True, but not the cause of **this error**. (error message mentions `get`, not `getElementsById`). I guess the error is just the page not being loaded at the time of the script execution.

Comment: That is true. Maybe there's an error in escaping the quotes or something? I know I copied that string into jsfiddle, and got the same error. Then I cleaned everything up, including the getElementsById, and it ran without error. It could have been something else I changed.